# Reference request: Cauchy product converges to zero

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, reference-request

I am looking for a reference for the following result:

Let $\sum_{n\ge 0} x_n$ be a absolutely convergent series and $(y_n)_{n\to\infty}$ be a complex sequence with $\lim_{n\to \infty} y_n=0$. Then $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N x_ny_{N-n}=0$.

It is not difficult to write down a direct proof of the fact (see below), but for using the result in a paper, providing a suitable reference seems to be more adequate. We previously posted the question on mathoverflow, but it was deemed to be out of scope and deleted there and we were referred to this site.

One might see this as an analogy of the well-known result that the Cauchy product of an absolutely convergent series and a convergent series is convergent; but we replace a convergent series by a sequence tending to zero both in the assumption as well as in the assertion.

*Proof:* Let $\epsilon>0$. Chooose $N_1$ such that 
$$\sum_{n\ge N_1} |x_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{2 \max_{n\ge 0} |y_n|}$$
and $N_2$ such that
$$|y_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{2 \sum_{n\ge 0} |x_n| }$$
for $n\ge N_2$.

Then
$$\biggl|\sum_{n\ge 0} x_n y_{N-n}\biggr| = \biggl|\sum_{n\ge 0} x_{N-n} y_n\biggr|\le \sum_{0\le n<N_2} |x_{N-n}||y_n| +\sum_{n\ge N_2} |x_{N-n}||y_n| < \epsilon$$
for $N\ge N_1+N_2$ by the estimates above.

Comment: Alternative proof that might help lead to a reference: defining $y_{-1}=0$, the result Wikipedia calls [Merten's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Convergence_and_Mertens.27_theorem) says that

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N x_n y_{N-n}=\sum_{N=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^N x_n (y_{N-n}-y_{N-n-1}) = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (y_n-y_{n-1})\right )=0.$$

Comment: Make that "Mertens'" not "Merten's", and a reference for that theorem is Apostol's Mathematical Analysis, 5th Ed Theorem 8.46 (Infinite Series and Infinite Products, Multiplication of Series).

Comment: @Dap, thank you, that's a much nicer proof which clarifies the relation with Mertens' theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second half of the proof of Theorem 8.46 (Merten's theorem) in Apostol's Mathematical Analysis, 2nd Ed, exactly proves the statement here with almost the same proof as outlined in my question.